# Gallery inside Dialog, OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, gallery, thumbnails

I created simple gallery but when I try to display it after few second when it is visible app crash and I get error :

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 31961100 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 19MB until OOM"
```

I must addmit that it happen when I try to display in gallery just one photo with size less than 1MB

Probably all this happen because I get this .jpg file and it should be decoded Bitmap ? or maybe because I doesn't create thumbnail of it ? Still one photo takes 160RAM?!?! quite strange.  What should I do If I want it to work fast and smooth fow more than 1 picture :). Some example code will be great.

Below all my code to do that

Dialog Gallery :

```
public void openDialog() {

        inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        // Dialog layout
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_choice, null);

        // Get gridView from dialog_choice
        gV = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        // GridAdapter (Pass context and files list)
        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, photoList);

        // Set adapter
        gV.setAdapter(adapter);

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder2.setTitle("MY GALLERY");
        builder2.setView(v);
        builder2.setPositiveButton("NEXT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("BACK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder2.setCancelable(false);
        builder2.create().show();
    }
```

GridAdapter :

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<File> listFiles;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<File> files) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.listFiles = files;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listFiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listFiles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.my_grid, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(listFiles.get(position).toString()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Rest used code to do that :

```
public ArrayList<File> photoList;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.guide_photo_album);
        photoList = imageReader(my_root);
}


    private ArrayList<File> imageReader(File root)
    {
        ArrayList<File> a = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files = root.listFiles();
        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
            if(files[i].isDirectory())
            {
                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                a.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));
            }
            else
            {
                if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
                {
                    a.add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

P.S sorry for weak and chaotic language.

Comment: Do you think that is helpful ? Simple app which use 160mb Ram and your idea is allow app to get more Ram lol

Comment: Dear, Please write your question properly, What is the meaning of 160RAM??..Mention MB(Ex : 160MB RAM) So,Viewer can undesrtand properly..I have one suggestion Learn how to use Picasso or Glide or Universal Loader for making Image Gallery type of application and also learn How to compress Bitmap programatically.

Answer (score 0):

use Glide library for showing images in Gallery
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: And how to do all this stuff and where should I implement it + still It will be same file so still there will be out of memory problems. Just faster displaying/loading